# Sort javascript key names

Tags: javascript

This is my code I have successfully sorted and got my final result to be what I wanted. Now I want to also sort so that the object name that contains the key word "newitem" will always get sorted to the bottom.

```
    var testgogo = {
      "newitemwrewt": {
        "brand": {
          "gdhshd": true
        },
        "stock": 2,
        "sold": 3
      },
      "other": {
        "brand": {
          "gdhshd": true
        },
        "stock": 2,
        "sold": 3
      },
      "newitemncnc": {
        "brand": {
          "gdhshd": true
        },
        "stock": 2,
        "sold": 3
      },
    };
    finalresult = Object
      .keys(testgogo)
      .sort(
        (a, b) =>
        (testgogo[a].stock !== undefined) - (testgogo[b].stock !== undefined) 
 || testgogo[a].stock - testgogo[b].stock 
|| testgogo[b].sold - testgogo[a].sold )[0];
    console.log(finalresult);
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: ^ Worth noting that while relevant, object order **is** guaranteed now. Though most of the better answers on those delve into that a bit.

Comment: I used Object.keys in my code. how do I sort them so key names that contain the word "newitem" should always go to bottom? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Javascript objects can't be ordered. 
If you need that data to be in an order you should make it an array.

Comment: This is not true anymore, though I agree with it in practice.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I guess it's just not a great habit to get into though. This is why we have mapping and filtering functions.

Comment: I used Object.keys in my code. how do I sort them so key names that contain the word "newitem" should always go to bottom? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object based on whether the key [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) the string `"newitem"`. Then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert the sorted entries back to an object

```js
const testgogo={newitemfgre:{brand:{gdhshd:!0},stock:2,sold:3},fruit:{brand:{grgrdgdr:!0,ggyugy:!0},stock:3,sold:2},vegetable:{brand:{htrhtr:!0},stock:1,sold:1},newitemwrewt:{brand:{gdhshd:!0},stock:2,sold:3},other:{brand:{gdhshd:!0},stock:2,sold:3},newitemncnc:{brand:{gdhshd:!0},stock:2,sold:3},snack:{brand:{htrhr:!0},stock:1,sold:4},afga:{brand:{gdhshd:!0},stock:1,sold:2},other:{brand:{gdhshd:!0},stock:2,sold:3}};

const str = "newitem";

const sortedEntries = Object.entries(testgogo)
              .sort((a, b) => a[0].includes(str) - b[0].includes(str));
      
const output = Object.fromEntries(sortedEntries)

console.log(output)
```

Subtracting booleans returns a 1, -1 or 0.

```
true - false === 1
false - true === -1
true - true === 0
```

So, if `a[0]` has `"newitem"` but `b[0]` doesn't, the key at `a[0]` will be moved to the end of the entries array.

Comment: can you use object.keys to do this? I used object.keys in my code, how do I sort them so key names that contain the word "newitem" should always go to bottom? thanks

Comment: when testing this code at this site https://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html , the console log shows the object names contain "newitem" still don't go to bottom

Comment: @Tosps `Object.keys` creates an array of keys `[key1, key2, ..]` etc while `Object.entries` creates an array of key-value tuples. `[ [key1, value1], [key2, value2]... ]`. This is why I use `a[0].includes`. If you have keys `Object.keys(testgogo)
              .sort((a, b) => a.includes(str) - b.includes(str))` This just gives an array of sorted keys

Comment: The advantage with `Object.entries` is that you can just use `Object.fromEntries` to convert it back to an object. With array of keys, you'd have to `reduce` the sorted keys to create an object.

Comment: @Tosps it works fine in the snippet. By the way, it won't modify the original object, it will create a new object.

Comment: Thanks I added ||a.includes(str) - b.includes(str)  to my code, it worked in console log

Comment: @Tosps you're welcome. Please upvote and [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255)